# jquery targeting the next character

Tags: jquery

Im trying to target the next '.' in a heading using jquery.

so right now the heading is

```
<h1 class="page-head">Explore. Think. Connect.</h1>
```

and my jquery is

```
 $(h1.page-head:contains(.)').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('.','<span class=\'nice-point\'>&#46;</span>')
  );
});
```

I was wondering how to target the other 2 '.' separately to add styling to them.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to separate the 3 words with spans in the html or is that not possible?

Comment: you can break these three words and easily traverse and replace it. I think that would be much easier.

Comment: @AndrewNgo its a wordpress page title- so no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to apply specific styles to each occurrence that comes up, you can queue up the styles you wish to apply in the order of the dots appearing in the text.

like.

```
$("h1.page-head:contains(.)").each(function(){

  newHTML = $(this).html()
  .replace('.','<span style=\'color:#F00;\'>&#46;</span>')
  .replace('.','<span style=\'color:#40F;\'>&#46;</span>')
  .replace('.','<span style=\'color:#0F4;\'>&#46;</span>')    

  $(this).html(newHTML);


});
```

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/HCgC7/)

The above example applies `style=\'color:#F00;\'` to the first dot,  `style=\'color:#40F;\'` to the second dot,  `style=\'color:#0F4;\'` to the third dot respectively. I think this is what you meant by separately adding styles to each dot. Sorry if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, using [the overload of `.html()` which accepts a function:](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

```
$('h1.page-head:contains(.)').html(function (index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/\./g, '<span class="nice-point">&#46;</span>');
});
```

If you want to do something different for each `.` in the `oldHtml`, you can get fancier, [since `replace()` accepts a function as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), or you can use any other desired string manipulation:

```
$('h1.page-head:contains(.)').html(function (index, oldHtml) {
    // equivalent to the code above; just an example
    return oldHtml.split('.').join('<span class="nice-point">&#46;</span>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! - sorry im a jquery noob. How would I specify the three individually?

Comment: If you know there will always be 3 items to replace, a simple variation on the `String.split()` example above would suffice. You could also do it by passing a function as the second argument of `String.replace()`, which I linked to relevant docs for. Give it a shot; it's fairly simple. There are lots of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: @MattBall im definitely doing something wrong - now two '..' are showing.